# Getting access to database in the docker container on VM

Tags: docker, mariadb, virtual-machine, windows-7-x64, docker-machine

I work on PC under Windows 7 x64.

I installed the OracleVM, then installed there Ubuntu 18.04. In Ubuntu, I installed Docker and created and run an environment with PHP, Nginx, and MariaDB and I managed to set up a Drupal 8 site there. All works successfully, and I managed to get access to the site from a browser on my Windows PC. I set it up using mapping the ports on VM settings.

But I don't know how to get access to my database in that container from a windows client, for example, from HeidiSQL. Mapping the ports doesn't help me, unfortunately.

Here are the list of my containers

```
example3_project_adminer     /entrypoint.sh php -S 0.0. ...   Up      9000/tcp            
example3_project_mailhog     MailHog                          Up      1025/tcp, 8025/tcp  
example3_project_mariadb     /docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld     Up      3306/tcp            
example3_project_nginx       /docker-entrypoint.sh sudo ...   Up      80/tcp              
example3_project_php         /docker-entrypoint.sh sudo ...   Up      9000/tcp            
example3_project_portainer   /portainer --no-auth -H un ...   Up      9000/tcp            
example3_project_traefik     /traefik -c /dev/null --we ...   Up      0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp
```

Could you clarify me, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it.
First, I added ports forwarding in the configuration of my mariadb container.

[image: the mariadb configuration]

I executed the following docker commands

```
docker-compose stop
docker-compose up -d
```

later, I added a new rule in the VM port forwarding rules

[image: VM port forwarding rules]

Now I'm able to connect to the database from my windows client program

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to confidently answer without a minimal verifiable example of your problem, such as docker invocation in this case. But I'd guess that you're not exposing the MariaDB port to the docker host OS (Ubuntu 18.04).

Look at how `nginx` is working, as that's clearly exposed, and make sure your `mariadb` container does similar ( probably with port 3306 the mysql/mariadb port).

Once you can connect from the Ubuntu machine, you should be able to map the port through the Oracle VM in turn.

Comment: I output list of Docker containers.
They are here
`
example3_project_mariadb     /docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld     Up      3306/tcp            
example3_project_nginx       /docker-entrypoint.sh sudo ...   Up      80/tcp              
`

Comment: why not add that to your question?

Comment: Added. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Thanks for that.  How are you executing these docker containers?  Are you using some orchestration layer above docker?  Or are you perhaps invoking docker directly?

Comment: I'm novice in using docker, I'm a Drupal programmer and I have installed [docker4drupal](https://github.com/wodby/docker4drupal) using [this article](https://niklan.net/blog/172)

Comment: In that case I'd recommend you rephrase this quesiton in terms of using docker4drupal.  Sorry, I don't know that platform, but if you mention it in the question maybe someone else will.

Comment: Hint:  You can't use 'localhost'.